# Laravel on server fails find all the classes in app.css

Tags: css, laravel, sass, vue.js

I'm designing a site using Laravel Mix on local. I have lots of scss lifes in `resources/assets/sass` and through `app.scss` I combine them it looks just the way it's supposed to be on local using `npm run watch` and `php artisan serve`

But when I set the site up on a server, all the css classes are missing, therefore design doesn't implement itself on the website. For instance I have a class `future-concerts` which styles the element it suggests. So I check for `.future-concerts` inside `public\css\app.css` there is no such class. What might be causing this? Even just copying `app.css` file to the server doesn't work. It just deletes most of the lines I wrote.

app.scss file

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abhaya+Libre|Mitr|Raleway');

// Variables
@import "variables";
@import "custom";
@import "directives";

// Bootstrap
@import "bootstrap.min";
@import "bootstrap-theme.min";

// Fotorama
@import "fotorama";

// Animate.css
@import "animate";

// Font Awesome
@import "font-awesome.min";
```

webpack.mix.js file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: show your `app.scss` and `webpack.mix` file

Comment: Here you go....